# Listen to Firefox WebExtension sidebar closing

Tags: addeventlistener, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-sidebar

I am working on a WebExtension using the sidebar.

When the sidebar is open, the extension performs some operations on the current tab. When it is closed, I want to revert these operations.

Is this possible? I didn't see methods like `browser.sidebarAction.addEventListener`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I adapted GnxR's idea in the following:

`extension/page/sidebar.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="panel"></div>
        <script src="static.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`extension/page/static.js`:

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  console.log('Sidebar will be closed!');
  // Do stuff
});
window.addEventListener('pagehide', (event) => {
  console.log('Sidebar is hidden!');
  // Do stuff
});
window.addEventListener('unload', (event) => {
  console.log('Sidebar is unloaded!');
  // Do stuff
});
```

When closing the extension (both from the cross bar and programmatically), I get the following in the browser console:

```
Sidebar is hiding! static.js:6:3
Sidebar is unloaded! static.js:10:3
```

Therefore it seems that both `pagehide` and `unload` events can be used,
but that `beforeunload` is never fired.

Answer (score 1):

The sidebar is an alsmot-regular independent webpage, in which you can listen to usual JS events. In order to know when the sidebar is closing, you can use [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) in the sidebar's JavaScript:

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  console.log('Sidebar is closing!');
  // Do stuff
});
```